# Regex - Regular expression for counting no.of digits between alphabets

Tags: python, regex

Need to construct a regular expression that counts numbers between alphabets.

```
schowalte3rguss77ie85  - 2
xyz1zyx - 1
x1y1z1 - 2
```

I have constructed this . But this doesn't work for case 3.
`[[a-z]+[0-9]+[a-z]]*`
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Terminology is important: a number is not the same concept as a digit. An alphabet is not the same concept as a letter.

Answer (score 3):

Use regx:

`(?<=[a-z])\d+(?=[a-z])`

[image]

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/tpss6x/1

[Javascript]

Answer (score 2):

If you want a count only, the last part should be a lookahead assertion.

If you want to also match uppercase chars, you can make the pattern case insensitive.

```
[a-z]\d+(?=[a-z])
```

**Explanation**

- `[a-z]` Match a single char a-z
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?=[a-z])` Positive lookahead, assert a char a-z to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nLu9nq/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
(?<=[^\W\d_])\d+(?=[^\W\d_])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JQHjog/1). If you want to only support ASCII letters, replace `[^\W\d_]` (that matches any Unicode letter) with `[a-zA-Z]`.

*Details*:

- `(?<=[^\W\d_])` - immediately before the current location, there must be any Unicode letter
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?=[^\W\d_])` - immediately after the current location, there must be any Unicode letter.

Counting can be done with `len(...)`, see [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/1TCVIl):

```py
import re
text = "schowalte3rguss77ie85"
matches = re.findall(r'(?<=[^\W\d_])\d+(?=[^\W\d_])', text)
print(len(matches)) # => 2
```